# How do I change the middle of the link Discord bot API

Tags: python, discord, bots

Question, does anyone know how to change URL through discord bot

So to explain it a bit more, I have a link, for example:
`https://Test.com/1/Test` and I want the "1" to change on command cause it gives me the output through a .txt that the bot puts in as a message in the discord channel

So for example if I do .New then it changes the "1" in the original link to the new one and from their prints the output through the .txt I already have a API for it i just need to know how to do this with a discord bot. I already made it work with just the Python Console by this code:

```
1 = input("")
loc = print (get('https://Test.com/' + (1) +'/json/').text)
```

but then with the actual site name of course, but I don't know if it is going to block it then.

So it would look like this:

```
User sent command: .Check Test
Bot sends text that they got from Link https://Test.com/Test/json
```

Comment: `1` is the acutual number, so you cant use it as a variable. `middle_part = input("")` and then `loc = print (get('https://Test.com/' + middle_part +'/json/').text) ` should work

Comment: Thanks for the fast awnser, But the 1 is not really what is there in the code but i was trying to make it easier to understand to just put 1, so sorry for not making that clear in the question. And im trying to get it to work with a Discord Bot and that is where im stuck at ATM cuase i just got into discord bot and dont know alot about them.

Comment: `url` is a string so you can use any string function with url - ie. `replace()`. You can also use `string formatting` or `f-string` to create new url. There is also module `urllib.parse` which can be useful in some situations.

Comment: Do you have a idea of what the code should look like? So i kinda know where to start because i couldnt find it anywhere on google. or if it is short then paste the exact code if possible.